# Script parou de funcionar no Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Estou com um problema que acredito ser muito incomum, dentro do Sharepoint Online na pasta Páginas do Site criei um novo e chamei de Dashboard. No Dashboard inseri uma webpart de conteúdo e coloquei um código html e uma chamada para um carregar um script que está em outra pasta no mesmo site.

O html funciona normal e quando está em modo de edição de página o script funciona, porém, quando saio não funciona mais. Já procurei em tudo e não encontro o motivo, alguma ajuda?

Comment: Verifique o código servido pela página quando ela não está em modo de edição. O código Javascript está lá? A referência (o caminho) está correta?

Comment: Sim a referência está correta. Tanto que ele funciona quando em modo de edição, ele executa minhas rest calls e retorna o conteúdo.

Comment: E fora do modo de edição?

Comment: Fora quando clico no botão onde ele deveria carregar a função nada acontece. Já até cheguei a dar check-out e check-in no main.js para ver se poderia ser alguma coisa do arquivo mas não adiantou.

Comment: Deixa eu perguntar de outra forma... Quando não está no modo de edição, o script está presente na página? Ele não dispara nenhum tipo de erro no console?

Comment: Não. O script está em um arquivo .js dentro de Site Assets e faço a chamada dele no html. Ainda agora funcionou normal sem a edição mas agora já não está funcionando novamente. No console não da erro.

Answer (score 3):

Bom depois de tanto pesquisar descobri que meu problema era em relação a um recurso do Sharepoint chamado “Minimal Download Strategy” que redireciona a url que estou usando para uma outra para otimizar a execução. O que precisei fazer no final foi simples, apenas entrar em:

Configurações do site > Gerenciar recursos do site > Mínimo Download estratégia (Desativar).

Isso tornou possível que o script fosse executado normalmente. Mais informações no link abaixo onde descobri a solução:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/improve-page-load-times-using-minimal-download-strategy-HA103692072.aspx